# Why is my function evaluated multiple times?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am having interesting situation that i am trying to understand. On surface everything works fine, but I had to debug something in a function and noticed that it gets called multiple times (to be exact 5 times) even though I am using it only in one place. I have this markup in the view, that sets up max length of the input field.

```
<div class="name-field">
            <input placeholder="ID" type="text" id="form_ID" name="searchId" autofocus
                data-ng-model="vm.searchCriteria.searchId" data-ng-required="vm.isSearchIdRequired"
                data-ng-minlength="1" data-ng-maxlength="{{vm.getMaxLengthForSearchId()}}"
                data-ng-class="{'input-error': vm.isSearchIdValid}">
        </div>
```

`getMaxLengthForSearchId()` returns a max length based on some check boxes being selected. I have three controllers into which I inject my viewModel, one for each view. There is one outer view and two that are contained within the outer view. All in all there are 5 scopes that I can see in Batarang in developer tools, including the scope for the outer controller. I would not have expected that this would be evaluated for every scope? What am I doing wrong?

```
Scope 1 (searchCtrl)
   Scope 2
      Scope 3 (searchFormCtrl)
   Scope 4
      Scope 5 (searchResultCtrl)
```

As I mentioned each one of these controllers is dependent upon searchViewModel. I can see that it is being instantiated only once, but function is called 5 times. Please helpe me understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common question.

Any function* referenced in an expression in your template will be evaluated during a $digest.

To work around this, you'd want to precalculate values on your scope properties where possible. You can do this with things like ng-change an other events.

---

*(almost all: It depends on how the directive using the expression is set up)

Comment: Wow, is this a hidden gem of angular? If I had call to remote service it would call it 5 times. Did not come across this warning anywhere, but I also started with angular 5 days ago, so it might be a common knowledge.

Comment: Well, the MV* architecture would tell you that you should be using a model to carry state to and from the view, and your controller should be doing all of the "work"... so binding functions to the view should really be avoided. The nicety of putting a function on the $scope is really so you can set up events like ng-click and the like.

Comment: I see what you are saying, however, I use controllers just to wire view with viewmodels and that is it. I almost have no logic on the controllers. I just need to switch it from asking (call to function) to imperative (telling viewModel to change the value I am binding view to)